# Javascript Response from Rails Controller leads to Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cytoscape.js

I have a form that creates a relation and when the form is submitted, javascript code that addes the newly connected nodes and the relations connecting them to the cytoscape graph should be returned:

The form:

```
<%= form_for Relation.new, :url => url_for(:controller => 'relations', :action => 'add_dependency'), remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :to_id, :value => @article.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :graph, :value => 1 %>
  <%= f.select :from_id, [], {}, {class: "select-article"} %>
  <%= f.submit "Add a dependency of this article." %>
<% end %>
```

The controller code:

```
  def add_dependency
    @relation = Relation.find_or_create_by(relation_params)
    @relation.user << current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @relation.save
        elements = json_for_cytoscape(@relation.from.self_and_all_dependencies_of_depth_and_less(3))
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @relation }
        format.js { render js: "ancestors.add( #{elements} ); console.log('Hello');" }
      else
        format.json { render json: @relation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I get this error (and no "Hello") in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.self-8944eaf3f9a2615ce7c830a810ed630e296633063af8bb7441d5702fbe3ea597.js?body=1:244)
    at rails-ujs.self-8944eaf3f9a2615ce7c830a810ed630e296633063af8bb7441d5702fbe3ea597.js?body=1:173
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.self-8944eaf3f9a2615ce7c830a810ed630e296633063af8bb7441d5702fbe3ea597.js?body=1:228)
```

This is the response:

```
ancestors.add( {:edges=>[], :nodes=>[{:data=>{:id=>200, :title=>"Test Yourself: Area & arc length using calculus", :href=>"http://localhost:3000/articles/200", :rank=>0.000459770114943, :color=>"grey"}}]} ); console.log('Hello');
```

Comment: What was the rendered response there? (you can find out in browser's network tab)

Comment: Do you have to wrap it in script tags maybe?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I added it to the question.

Comment: @unflores No, this worked with a simpler script (that just reloaded the site) without a script tag.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by adding to_json:

```
json_for_cytoscape(@relation.from.self_and_all_dependencies_of_depth_and_less(3)).to_json
```

Answer (score 0):

That response is not valid javascript and the reason is pretty simple. When you cast a Ruby hash to a string the result is not valid JS:

```
irb(main):001:0> { :foo => 'bar'}.to_s
=> "{:foo=>\"bar\"}"
```

Instead you need to encode it as JSON.

```
irb(main):003:0> { :foo => 'bar'}.to_json
=> "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

Due to quoting issues is easier done if you actually create a view instead of rendering inline:

```
ancestors.add( <%= elements.to_json %> ); 
console.log('Hello');
```